# Creating Custom Glyphicons Icon/Font on Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, glyphicons

Thanks to Mike Causer's post on creating Custom Glyphicons Icon/Font on Bootstrap 3 I have followed these steps but do not know how to finalize it!, 
1- Created a Custom SVG file named `xoo.svg`
2- Dragged and Dropped the `xoo.svg` to Fontello.com 
3- Downloaded The Font with name of `icon-xoo` file contains following Files and Folders:

[image]

Can you please let me know if I have to put all of this codes in Bootstrap 3 Fonts and CSS folders? How and where can I Register the CSS files?
since the icon code is `0xe800` can I have a CSS claim like:

```
.icon-xoo { &:before { content: "\0xe800"; } }
```

and Finally, how should I call it? is this correct way to do that?

```
<span class="glyphicon icon-xoo"></span>
```

Thanks

Comment: A link to the post that you mentioned would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add an entry for `.icon-xoo` in [`bootstrap/less/glyphicons.less`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/glyphicons.less) and change the value of [the Less variable `@icon-font-name`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/4bf0645060fb421c9b9f6f3309aceb42dd6e3407/less/variables.less#L78) to "icon-xoo". You should put the font files in `../fonts/` (relative to your `bootstrap.css`).